# Monad State not Updating

Tags: haskell, state, monads

I'm trying to create use a state monad to store the current state of a game that takes in a list of statement (commands) to return a list of actions.

Individually, the turbo commands work, but done sequentially, the previous commands do not have any affect on the current command.

Something I don't really understand is how are the states suppose to be propagated down to the next commands? The following is what I would do if I was running the code manually:

```
s0 = turbo (PenDown)
s1 = turbo (Forward (RLit 50))
s2 = turbo (Turn (RLit 90))
s3 = turbo (Forward (RLit 50))
s4 = turbo (Turn (RLit 90))
s5 = turbo (Forward (RLit 50))

a1 = snd (deState s1 (fst (deState s1 (fst (deState s0 initTurboMem)))))
a2 = snd (deState s3 (fst (deState s2 (fst (deState s1 (fst (deState s1 (fst (deState s0 initTurboMem)))))))))
a3 = snd (deState s5 (fst (deState s4 (fst (deState s3 (fst (deState s2 (fst (deState s1 (fst (deState s1 (fst (deState s0 initTurboMem)))))))))))))
a = a1 ++ a2 ++ a3
```

This would give the answer, but I'm not sure how it would be done in the code below.

To run the code, use the following

```
stmt = Seq [ 
             PenDown
           , Forward (RLit 50)
           , Turn (RLit 90)    
           , Forward (RLit 50)    
           , Turn (RLit 90)    
           , Forward (RLit 50)   
           ]  
snd (deState (turbo stmt) initTurboMem)
```

Here is the function in question that isn't taking previous statements into consideration

```
turbo (Seq [x]) = turbo x
turbo (Seq (x:xs)) = do
    state <- get
    let a0 = snd (deState (turbo x) state)
    state <- get
    let a1 = snd (deState (turbo (Seq xs)) state)
    pure (a0 ++ a1)
```

Here are the rest of the functions

```
turbo :: Stmt -> State TurboMem [SVGPathCmd]
turbo (var := expr) = do
    state <- get
    let val = snd (deState (evalReal expr) state)
    setVar var val
    pure []
turbo PenDown = do
    setPen True
    pure []
turbo PenUp = do
    setPen False
    pure []
turbo (Turn expr) = do
    state <- get
    let angle = snd (deState (evalReal expr) state)
    turn angle
    pure []
turbo (Forward expr) = do
    state <- get
    let angle = snd (deState (getAngle) state)
        dist = snd (deState (evalReal expr) state)
        x = dist * cos (angle * pi / 180)
        y = dist * sin (angle * pi / 180)
        pen = snd (deState (getPen) state)
    if pen then pure [LineTo x y] else pure [MoveTo x y]
```

The turbo state

```
data TurboMem = TurboMem (Map String Double) Double Bool
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The expressions and statements

```
data RealExpr
    = RLit Double               -- literal/constant
    | RVar String               -- read var's current value
                                -- if uninitialized, the answer is 0
    | Neg RealExpr              -- unary minus
    | RealExpr :+ RealExpr      -- plus
    | RealExpr :- RealExpr      -- minus
    | RealExpr :* RealExpr      -- times
    | RealExpr :/ RealExpr      -- divide
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
data Stmt
    = String := RealExpr        -- assignment, the string is var name
    | PenDown                   -- set pen to down (touch paper) state
    | PenUp                     -- set pen to up (away from paper) state
    | Turn RealExpr             -- turn counterclockwise by given degrees
                                -- negative angle just means clockwise
    | Forward RealExpr          -- move by given distance units (in current direction)
                                -- negative distance just means backward
                                -- if pen is down, this causes drawing too
                                -- if pen is up, this moves without drawing
    | Seq [Stmt]                -- sequential compound statement. run in given order
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
data SVGPathCmd = MoveTo Double Double -- move without drawing
                | LineTo Double Double -- draw and move
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)
```

Helper functions to manipulate the state

```
-- Get current direction.
getAngle :: State TurboMem Double
-- Change direction by adding the given angle.
turn :: Double -> State TurboMem ()
-- Get pen state.
getPen :: State TurboMem Bool
-- Set pen state.
setPen :: Bool -> State TurboMem ()
-- Get a variable's current value.
getVar :: String -> State TurboMem Double
-- Set a variable to value.
setVar :: String -> Double -> State TurboMem ()
```

The initial state

```
initTurboMem = TurboMem Map.empty 0 False
```

I expect the result to be

```
[LineTo 50.0 0.0,LineTo 0.0 50.0,LineTo -50.0 0.0]
```

but what I actually get is

```
[MoveTo 50.0 0.0,MoveTo 50.0 0.0,MoveTo 50.0 0.0]
```

Comment: Quick question: in words, what is `turbo` supposed to do? Understanding the intended purpose may help with diagnosing the problem.

Comment: @bradrn ```turbo``` is suppose to take in a ```Stmt``` and return ```State``` with the resulting ```TurboMem``` (stores the state of the Map and variables) and a list of ```SVGPathCmd``` (which are just ```MoveTo x y``` and ```LineTo x y``` determined by the Statements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
turbo (Seq [x]) = turbo x
turbo (Seq (x:xs)) = do
    state <- get
    let a0 = snd (deState (turbo x) state)
    state <- get
    let a1 = snd (deState (turbo (Seq xs)) state)
    pure (a0 ++ a1)
```

Here, `deState (turbo x) state` returns a pair `(newState, a0)`, and `newState` is simply discarded by `snd`. So, the next `state <- get` will read the original state again. Essentially, the state "in the monad" never change throughout the execution of `Seq (x:xs)`, when it should.

The problem here is that you are using `deState` in a monadic computation. You should not, since that requires you to manually keep track of what is the "current" state, and pass it around like this:

```
let (state0,a0) = deState (turbo x0) state
    (state1,a1) = deState (turbo x1) state0
    (state2,a2) = deState (turbo x2) state1
    ...
```

Writing in this way works, but it is *precisely* what the state monad helps to avoid! We should write instead

```
a0 <- turbo x0
a1 <- turbo x1
a2 <- turbo x2
...
```

and let the monad deal with the state passing boilerplate.

I would rewrite the `turbo (Seq ...)` cases as follows:

```
turbo (Seq []) = pure []
turbo (Seq (x:xs)) = do
    a0 <- turbo x
    a1 <- turbo (Seq xs)
    pure (a0 ++ a1)
```

Much simpler, since now `turbo x` feels like a function call in an imperative language, which can modify the state variables with a side effect -- and that's what the state monad is about. We do not have to track the current state explicitly, and pass it around.

Try to remove all other uses of `deState` in your code. You should only use `deState` once: outside of `turbo`, when you are "exiting the monad" and your return type is not longer of the form `State TurboMem something`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was wondering if I need to change how I check the following ```if (snd (deState (isVarBetween var from to) state)) then...```, assuming ```isVarBetween :: String -> Double-> Double-> State TurboMem Bool```

Comment: @loiuytre35 You can use `between <- isVarBetween var from to` and then `if between then ...` in the next line.

Comment: So you really don't need to use ```deState``` anywhere except for the first line of code executed for the initial state.

Comment: @loiuytre35 Yes, exactly: you need to use it only once at the very beginning to pass the initial state.

Comment: Why explicit recursion? Isn't this a perfect place for eg. `concatMapM`?

Comment: @moonGoose Sure, but the OP is clearly not yet familiar with the state monad, so I think it's beneficial to understand the basic approach before using a "magical" library function which solves the job.

Comment: Just to me, that ending point is *so* unnatural as to be insufficient I guess.